# Android Sqlite Column Exists but returned -1

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an android app where I've Created a Database Table named chats with the following Schema

```
package com.messaging.chatify.Schema;

public class Messages {
    public static final String TABLE_MESSAGES = "chats";
    public static final String MESSAGE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String MESSAGE_TEXT = "text";
    public static final String MESSAGE_ATTACHMENT = "attachement";
    public static final String MESSAGE_SENDER = "msgfrom";
    public static final String MESSAGE_RECEIVER = "msgto";
    public static final String MESSAGE_ISREAD = "isRead";
    public static final String MESSAGE_TIME = "mtime";

    public static final String[] ALL_COLUMNS = { MESSAGE_ID, MESSAGE_TEXT, MESSAGE_ATTACHMENT, MESSAGE_SENDER, MESSAGE_RECEIVER, MESSAGE_ISREAD };

    public static final String CREATE_STATEMENT =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_MESSAGES + "(" +
                MESSAGE_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                MESSAGE_TIME + " TEXT, " +
                MESSAGE_TEXT + " TEXT, " +
                MESSAGE_ATTACHMENT + " TEXT, " +
                MESSAGE_SENDER + " TEXT, " +
                MESSAGE_RECEIVER + " TEXT, " +
                MESSAGE_ISREAD + " INTEGER" + ");";

    public static final String DROP_STATEMENT =
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MESSAGES;
}
```

but unfortunately when I try to get the column mtime from this table,
I get -1

I've exported the database to my computer and checked it with sqlite browser, the column is created and exists

here are the screen shots of the sqlite browser schema and records

[SQLITE BROWSER SCHEMA OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osL95.png)

[SQLITE BROWSER DATA OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYF7F.png)

any suggestion how to get rid of this issue?

Comment: Wheres you query code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you may have omitted the column in :-

```
public static final String[] ALL_COLUMNS = { MESSAGE_ID, MESSAGE_TEXT, MESSAGE_ATTACHMENT, MESSAGE_SENDER, MESSAGE_RECEIVER, MESSAGE_ISREAD };
```

Perhaps changing it to be (i.e. adding **`MESSAGE_TIME`**):-

```
public static final String[] ALL_COLUMNS = { MESSAGE_ID, MESSAGE_TEXT, MESSAGE_ATTACHMENT, MESSAGE_SENDER, MESSAGE_RECEIVER, MESSAGE_ISREAD, MESSAGE_TIME };
```

will resolve the issue. If not then you need to edit your question to include the query that is resulting in the -1.

Alternatively, you could use :-

```
public static final String[] ALL_COLUMNS = {"*"};
```

- *P.S. for all columns you can use **`*`** (e.g. `SELECT * FROM mytable`) (as used in the alternative solution above) or if using the `query` method you can use `null` for all columns as the 2nd paremeter.*